# MarshalByRefObject/AppDomain callback using in-scoped variable fails with an error

Tags: c#, callback, marshalling, appdomain

I'm trying to pass an Action<> to an object in a different AppDomain and have run into a snarl.

Here's the code for the remote object:

```
public class RemoteEdit : MarshalByRefObject
{
     public RemoteEdit()
     {
     }

     public void DoEdit(Action<string> progress)
     {
           progress("Hello, World");
     }
}
```

And the code calling this remote object:

```
AppDomain d = AppDomain.CreateDomain("newDomain");
RemoteEdit edit = (RemoteEdit)d.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("MyLib", "MyLib.RemoteEdit");
edit.DoEdit((string dummy) => { 
     Console.WriteLine(dummy);           // This works!
});

int i = 0;
edit.DoEdit((string dummy) => {
     Console.WriteLine(i);               // This crashes.
});
```

The error thrown is:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in Edit.exe

Additional information: Type 'Edit.Edit+<>c__DisplayClass3' in assembly 'Edit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.
```

I *think* that `i` is part of a closure for the callback function in the second case, and that the remote class doesn't know how to deal with it.  But I can't reason out why `RemoteEdit` needs to know anything about `i` in the first place.  I think it would just have a method wrapped up with whatever objects are in the closure in either case.

Whats really going on here?  Better yet, how do I fix it?  (I own both classes, I could cheat and pass `i` in as part of the `DoEdit` call, and get it passed back to me in the callback... but that's distasteful.)  It wants something marked as serializable, but the object in question is an `int` and not a class.

Comment: This is a limitation you'll have to deal with.  The difference is that the `i` variable is captured by the lambda, that requires a class to store it.  Its name is `<>c_DisplayClass3`, a screwy name to ensure it doesn't match any of your classes.  And it is not serializable so it cannot be marshaled by value across the appdomain boundary.

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable answer.  I'd mark it as correct, but it's just a comment.